# MVC 4 ASP .NET Oracle 10g EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle10g, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have an `Oracle 10g DataBase` on production, and I need to deploy a new MVC 4 web application. I want to use `EntityFramework Database First` approach, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have read a lot, and some people say that you can make Oracle 10g work with Entity Framework 5, but I can't do it.

In DataProviders `Oracle Database` is not listed, but it is in connections explorer.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, and I'll write the solution down here for future reference.

I'm using `Visual Studio Ultimate 2013`. I clean all the ODAC previous installations and installed the latest one that is `ODAC 12c Release 2 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.1.2)`. And its working with `Entity Framework 5`.

I hope it helps someone.